# Installing Jenkins as a window service is throwing error

Tags: jenkins

Installing Jenkins as a windows service is throwing below error -

Can you help m to trouble shoot the issue.

OS : Windows 2012 server R2

.Net framework : 4.0

> java.io.IOException: Failed to shellExecute: 1223     at
>   hudson.lifecycle.WindowsInstallerLink.runElevated(WindowsInstallerLink.java:304)
>     at
>   hudson.lifecycle.WindowsInstallerLink.doDoInstall(WindowsInstallerLink.java:141)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:335)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:175)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:108)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$10.dispatch(MetaClass.java:362)     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>     at
>   hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>     at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

How did you install? Remove it and start fresh.

1. Download Jenkins (2.3.1) - Current Version - [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)
2. After Download open the Command Prompt, change directory to where you Downloaded Jenkins
3. In the command prompt type: `java -jar jenkins.war` to run jenkins on a local server, you will see it display in console a password
4. Navigate to `http://localhost:8080/`
5. When Jenkins is opened it will ask you to enter the password from the console. Enter it and create a user ID
6. After you created an account you can add your plugins and go from there.

Comment: I have jenkins running in my local host.I got the error when i was trying to run it was a windows service from Manage Jenkins->Install as a windows service.I need to run it as a service to create jobs in Jenkins slaves

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to install it on Windows systems as a service is to use .exe installer.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run Jenkins in command prompt, make sure you run the command prompt with administrators right.

Next you run jenkins after set to jenkins directory using:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

Then try to install as windows service again